# How can I found where I defined JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, bash, java-home

Here is my system info

```
wangbo@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-72-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 31 14:07:41 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

When I check java version

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

but when I echo $JAVA_HOME

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
```

It is unmatched , It seems that I defined $JAVA_HOME somewhere , but I can`t found it , Anyone can help me how can I found my $JAVA_HOME defined

**Other useful info :**

1. I had install and uninstall jdk9 as first jdk before
2. It is not in ~/.bashrc
3. It is not in /etc/bash.bashrc
4. It is not in ~/.profile

**UPDATE**

```
wangbo@ubuntu:~$ more /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Comment: Try grepping in `~` and `/etc/`, e.g. `grep java-9-oracle /etc -R`.

Comment: use update-alternative or similar to reset to the default (here I have a `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh`)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1) `JAVA_HOME` is most probably defined in `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` and `/etc/profile.d/jdk.csh` These files are unfortunately not managed by the `update-alternatives` system.

2) Which executable you run should depend on the `update-alternatives` system, but if you have forced a particular version in your `PATH` it won’t.

Many java applications are actually invoked by scripts which choose their preferred jvm setting up a consistent environment, and shouldn’t be affected by your problem. It is best to have a consistent environment for free java invocations from the shell, however, and in most installations I know this is achieved manually...

Some java distributions don’t need JAVA_HOME at all. In other cases you need it. My advice is to define JAVA_HOME only when it turns out you need it. If it is the case, define it in a shell script and use that script to invoke the commands that you need that particular value for.

**EDIT**: `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` seems to be installed by `oracle-java8-set-default`.

```
# Uninstall the package (choose one)
sudo apt purge oracle-java8-set-default
sudo apt remove --purge oracle-java8-set-default

# Configure the desired Java binary
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: I delete `/etc/profile.d/jdk.sh` and reboot , **JAVA_HOME** is no longer exsit It seems that I have to config **JAVA_HOME** by myself and when I change Java version with `update-alternatives` I need to modify it again , is there any resolvent  ？

Comment: @Wangbo JAVA_HOME is not really needed in many cases. (It is if you use Oracle jvm.) I added paragraph to my answer with some advice.

Answer (score 0):

you should better check /etc/environment

Comment: Update It seems that I haven`t defined JAVA_HOME in  /etc/environment

Answer (score 0):

On my ubuntu 14.04 system, kernel 4.4.0-71-generic I used the following:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Java command is picked up from the `PATH` variable. Most probably, you have added Java7 to your path. Check your .profile, .bash_profile, /etc/profile and /etc/environment files.

`JAVA_HOME` is used by some scripts/tools (`ant` comes to mind) - to select a java command.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo find / -path /sys -prune -o -path /proc -prune -o -type f -exec grep -l JAVA_HOME {} + 2>/dev/null
```

Sorry the first version of my answer will take forever. But this will take only some time, but it will find the file.